# Efficient method to detect bounding-box (aabb) intersects a point cloud (2d)

Tags: tree, 2d, intersection, bounding-box

I was wondering what the most efficient method is to intersect a bounding box with a cloud of points.

- The points don't change, so setting up a tree structure makes sense.
- The bounding box is different for each check.
- Points have uneven density (otherwise bucketing into a grid might be a good option).

Currently I'm using a KD-tree, and doing a depth-first-search, first taking the branch closest to the boxes center when traversing each node.

This works quite well, however I was curious if this problem has a known solution which performs better (or may perform better in many cases).

---

### Message to whoever tagged for this to be closed:

This has been flagged to be closed as:
**asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource**

I am not asking for an existing library, I am interested in the possibility that a better **algorithm** exists to the one I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can put all points into the kd-tree it's a good solution. Maybe a r-tree or a quadtree can be faster. On the other hand a grid is most likely more efficient because it's a bit cheaper.